# Is Flow a derivative of a specific JavaScript version?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am not sure, but going by the docs, I couldn't find any such thing.
However, I was told that it is a derivative of a specific JS version, is it?
If so, which one is it?
Moreover, could someone provide me the resources for the same?

Comment: What does it even mean for a library to be "derivative of a specific JS version"?

Comment: Flow is a static analyzer. It's not even written in JavaScript (it's written in OCaml).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Typescript, Flow is not a compiler. The idea with Flow is that it is plain Javascript with added type annotations. To transpile code to strip the annotations, and to target specific JS environments you must use another tool, such as Babel. Because of that I don't think it is accurate to say that Flow is a derivative of any particular Javascript version.

It is important to note that when using Flow you can only use ECMAScript features that the Flow checker is designed to work with. Flow is updated regularly to add support for new features, like object spread properties. Sometimes support for experimental features is added behind an opt-in configuration option. For example can opt-in to support for optional chaining in Flow v0.71.0 or later. Adding support for new features is on ongoing process; and ECMAScript is generally backward compatible, which means that Flow is too. So you could say that Flow is associated with something close to the "latest" ECMAScript spec, but "latest" changes regularly.